# CAML Query Type as text, show all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, caml-query, caml

I have this query

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>21094460</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

It return all the item of my list. I tried a lot of solution found on Internet and Forum but no one solved my Problem.

Comment: Javascript? Looks like CSOM, but if you are using JSOM, the syntax is incorrect. Its camlQuery.set_viewXml("QUERY")

Comment: Try removing <View> and </View> from the query.